# XSLT: Colon in attribute name in source XML

Tags: android, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform the android xml into Plist but i am facing the issue because the Android XML contains COLONS in the attribute names as follows:

```
  <PreferenceCategory android_title="Identity" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="systemname"
            android_title="System Name" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
```

So when i try to read the attribute value using XSLT it gives the following error:

```
XPath evaluation returned no result.
```

I am bit new to XSLT, So  can any one help me reading the attribute value which have colon in their names as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by using the **exclude-result-prefixes** attribute inside  in XSLT.
My stylesheet tag looked like below.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 exclude-result-prefixes="android">
```

**exclude-result-prefixes** attribute is used if you want to exclude any namespace during compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about XML Namespaces, a good starting point can be [XML Namespaces tutorial on w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) to know about the usage of "colons".

You could read the MSDN article about [XML Namespaces and How They Affect XPath and XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx) to know more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I also tried to apply the namespace in the stylesheet, now error is not coming but still not able to extract the value....

Comment: Without looking at your stylesheet/code, all that one could do is speculate.