# How to access xml attributes which contains ':' charactor in their name?

Tags: c#, xml

.
I am new to c# . I am trying to parse an "AndroidManifest.xml" file.
While parsing i need to get the values of the some attributes of some elements.
Following is my "AndroidManifest.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.1.0" package="com.sbi.SBIFreedomPlus"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SBIFreedom" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.konylabs.android.KonyMapsActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity android:name="com.konylabs.android.KonyMapsV2Activity" />
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is my code to parse this xml :

```
void read()
    {
            try
            {
                string fileName = @"tempassets//AndroidManifest.xml";
                String applicationPackage = "";
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                applicationPackage = doc.Root.Attribute("package").Value;


                foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
                {
                    if (el.Name == "application")
                    {
                        foreach (XElement child in el.Elements())
                        {
                            if (child.HasElements)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("true");
                                MessageBox.Show("name:" + child.Name + "Label" + child.Attribute("android:label").Value);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("exception while parsing AndroidManifest.xml :"+objException);
                File.WriteAllText(@"tempassets//Config//error.txt", ""+objException, Encoding.Unicode);
            }
    }
```

But this gives me runtime exception  as:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

So can anyone tell me how should i resolve this exception to get values of such attribtes . . .
Thanx in advance . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT: Colon in attribute name in source XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050833/xslt-colon-in-attribute-name-in-source-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part before `:` is called the namespace prefix. When working with `System.Xml.Linq` you need to reference it like this:

```
child.Attribute("{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}label").Value
```

The URI you need to use is the one that is defined in the XML document using `xmlns:` prefix as

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

An alternative way is to use the [`XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx) class (note that in this case you are not using `{}` around the URI):

```
XNamespace android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
var attribute = child.Attribute(android + "label").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the `LocalName` property.

Example to retrieve apk's `versionName`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
  var nList = doc.Root.Attributes();

  foreach (var att in nList)
  {
      if (att.Name.LocalName == "versionName")
         return att.Value;
  }
```